# Insert new rows into tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powerbuilder

I am trying to execute a stored procedure which performs an `Insert` action but I am getting an error (as shown in the screenshot). Following is my PB code and the subsequent one is the declaration of my params in the stored procedure.

```
DECLARE sp_insert_EndorsementUnderlying_AP PROCEDURE FOR
                @EndNo = :endnum1,
                @PolicyId = :policyid1

USING SQLCA;

EXECUTE sp_insert_EndorsementUnderlying_AP;

CHOOSE CASE SQLCA.sqlcode
    CASE 0
        // Execute successful; no result set
        COMMIT;

    CASE ELSE
        MessageBox ("INSERT of New Endorsement Rows Failed",  &
            string (SQLCA.sqldbcode) + " = " + &
            SQLCA.sqlerrtext)
        RETURN 

END CHOOSE
```

Stored procedure declaration:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_insert_EndorsementUnderlying_AP]
    @EndNo SMALLINT,
    @PolicyId INT
AS
BEGIN
```

Error message:

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/error msg screen shot

Comment: The image link is broken.

Comment: why there's messagebox in stored procedure?

Comment: Also best not to name SP's starting with `sp_` as that is reserved for system SPs.

Comment: Where exactly your code fails and throws error?

Comment: The error which i am getting goes like "137 = Index #0 Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider Message: Must declare the scalar variable "@EndNO". Number : 137 State: 2"

Comment: When you execute your stored procedure are you passing in anything?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax in PB to declare a procedure is:

```
      DECLARE **PBPROCNAME** PROCEDURE FOR **DATABASEPROCNAME** 
@parm1 = :pbvariable1, @parm2 = :pbvariable2 USING SQLCA;
```

Which is not what you have in your example.  Can't comment on the error since your link does not work.

Comment: Thanks for that............The error which i am getting goes like "137 = Index #0 Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider Message: Must declare the scalar variable "@EndNO". Number : 137 State: 2"

Comment: So, you most probably miss the procedure name between `PROCEDURE FOR` and `@EndNo`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (note the slight difference procedure name - this is not compulsory but it helps make the difference between both worlds):

```
DECLARE pb_insert_EndorsementUnderlying_AP PROCEDURE FOR sp_insert_EndorsementUnderlying_AP 
                @EndNo = :endnum1,
                @PolicyId = :policyid1

USING SQLCA;

EXECUTE pb_insert_EndorsementUnderlying_AP;

CHOOSE CASE SQLCA.sqlcode
    CASE 0
        // Execute successful; no result set
        COMMIT;

    CASE ELSE
        MessageBox ("INSERT of New Endorsement Rows Failed",  &
            string (SQLCA.sqldbcode) + " = " + &
            SQLCA.sqlerrtext)
        RETURN 

END CHOOSE
```